# Dump Values of All Variables in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, variables, visual-studio-2012

My program does a funky thing where it works only *sometimes*, mostly after running it a few times. What I want to do is copy the values of all the variables of when it doesn't work and do the same for when it does work, then compare the two so I can try and locate the problem. Is there any easy way to do this? I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Just how many variables are we talking about because "Watch" and "Breakpoints" can do a lot.

Comment: Yes, try pressing F10 and F11 to do step-by-step debugging and keep on checking the variables value each time. And the funky thing you described about your code is the most common thing everybody's code do. So just relax and start over again. :-)

Comment: A lot of variables. I have no idea where the problem is so breakpoints are no help. My program only renders a few voxels and has basic camera control, so there'd be no point in restarting.

Comment: I have this problem. It's a database with literally thousands of variables. Somewhere in there is a variable containing the filename that it's reading from. I don't want to spend 3 days looking for it, i want to dump all the variables that VS can read to a file, and locate it in the file in 10 minutes. This will give me the name of the variable that it's contained in. Common sense really. If VS doesn't support this feature, it really should.